# Prevent bitmap caching in Animate CC canvas when applying effects

Tags: animate-cc

When working inside Animate CC in HTML5 canvas, effects like blur aren't updated when compiling. A warning states that

```
"Filters are very expensive and are not updated once applied".
```

Since the effect only applies to a small bitmap and is for local use only, I don't really care if it puts a load on the CPU/GPU - I need to animate the effect. No bitmap caching has been applied.

Is there any way of forcing Animate CC to make the project update on every frame?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, applying Filters or color effects on any Movieclip requires Cache as Bitmap to be applied to the Symbols in CreateJS. This causes such Movieclips to become static. If there is some animation inside such a Movieclip, you'll need to update the cache at every frame to play the animation correctly along with the desired filter/color effect.

You can add a code snippet like this inside such Movieclips:

```
if(!this.executed) {
    this.on("tick", function() {if(this.cacheID)this.updateCache();});
    this.executed = true;
}
```

PS: It does have a performance impact so avoid this for heavy usages.

Comment: Are there any additional settings that must be made to the movieclip? It does not produce any errors (when I remember to set the bitmap caching option on the movieclip itself) but the effect, such as shadow or blur, still isn't animated.